# First Database Structure help Please

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

This is my first time making my own mysql database, and I was hoping for some pointers. I've looked through previous questions and found that it IS possible to search multiple tables at once... so that expanded my posibilities.

What I am trying to do, is have a searchable / filterable listing of Snowmobile clubs  on a PHP page.

These clubs should be listable by state, county or searchable for by name / other contained info.

I'd also like them to be alphabetized in the results, despite the order of entry.

Currently my mind was in the place of, have a table for NY, PA etc

With Columns for County(varchar), Clubname(varchar), Street address (long text) , phone (varchar) email (varchar) website address (varchar)

Should I really be making multiple tables for each county, such as NY.ALBANY , NY.MADISON

Are the field formats I have chosen the sensible ones?

Should Address be broken into subcomponents... such as street1, street2, city, state, zip.

Eventually, I think I'd like a column "trailsopen" with a yes or no, and change the tr background to green or red based on input.

Hope this makes sense...

Comment: You should probably only have one table and have state as a column also. Not point in having multiple tables will only make it harder on yourself in the long run.

Comment: Just make sure you use your indexes well and you won't have any problems having them all in that one table.

Comment: @Pitchinnate this is terrible advice! That's like saying you shouldn't use more than one class in an object oriented language to make it easier. You should always split up things logically.

Comment: Mind expanding on using indexes well ?

Comment: so magnus, are you suggesting to keep as NY , PA tables, or further break down tables to state.county

Comment: @Magnus you create seperate classes or tables when you are storing or manipulating different information. The only difference in his tables as described is the state. You can simply have state as a column and make that an index for quicker searches. Would you store users in a db in separate tables based off the first letter? No that is just redundant and would be a pain.

Comment: @JohnMacKenzie no, one table for the states and one table for all the counties would be fine. You can then use indices as appropriate.

Comment: @Pitchinnate you should always store things that might need to be searchable independently together. It's entirely possible you might, for instance, want to look up things like ZIP codes by county. If you use one big table, you'll end up having to sift through extreme amounts of data sooner or later.

Comment: @Magnus you shouldn't be going through large amounts of data as long as you have your indexes setup correctly. Learn to use `explain` in mysql so you can see how efficient your queries are. Otherwise everything he wants to add a state to his db, he will have to create a new table and modify his code.

Comment: @Magnus also potentially down the road lets say he wants to add a location finder, where it finds the locations closest to that person. What if the person lives close to a border of a state. The closest location maybe in a completely different state. Would make this search quite difficult if you have each state separated into a separate table.

Comment: @Pitchinnate I didn't say to split up the states into individual tables per state. You ought to have one table with states. That's far easier to work with when things get bigger. But I might also have misinterpreted you there, it sounded like you suggested that he use only one table for *everything*, not one table

Comment: @Magnus yeah you misunderstood, the OP asked if he should store Snowmobile clubs from NY in a seperate table from Snowmobile clubs in PA, so you would end up having snowclub_ny, snowclub_pa, etc... as tables. I was saying he should have a table snowclub and store the state as a column as char(2) or and id that points to a state table.

Comment: @pitchinnate so you're saying just make one table clubs... and add another varchar column for state, otherwise continue as I have been... ?

Comment: @Pitchinnate ah alright, the *only one* table thing got me on the wrong track there. Guess we're pretty much on the same page after all, my bad ;).

Comment: maybe I'm on the wrong track too... ?

Comment: is there a benefit to having a table "state" with a stateid column in table snowclubs?

Comment: @Magnus I figured there was a misunderstanding. Otherwise I would hate to find some code and a db designed by you ;)

Comment: @Pitchinnate as would I, lol. Sadly I've seen a lot of those DBs in the wild so I tend to get a bit trigger happy when it comes to that :).

Comment: Only advantage of using a stateid column and having a table of states is for easier display. You can just do a query on the state table and pull all states to display in a <select> instead of having 50 lines of code everytime you have a state picker. Also that way you are indexing a int instead of a char or varchar.

Comment: if I had a table for ny.counties , would that help me tie multiple counties to a single entry in clubs w/ coulmn foreign state id

Comment: I'll post an answer with what I would recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would setup your db:

```
state
id (tinyint) //primary key auto incremented unsigned
short (varchar(2)) // stores NY, PA
long (varchar(20)) // Stores New York, Pennsylvania

county
id (int) //primary key auto incremented unsigned
state_id (tinyint) //points to state.id
name (varchar(50))

club_county
id (int) //primary key auto incremented unsigned
county_id (int) //points to county.id
club_id (int) //points to club.id

club
id (int) //primary key auto incremented unsigned
name (varchar(100))
address (varchar(100)
city (varchar(25))
zip (int)
etc...
```

Comment: can county_id handle multiple id's ?

Comment: No will need to seperate that into another table I will modify my answer.

Comment: There you go now you can have multiple club_county entries per club.

Comment: gotcha... thanks for your help. Is there any way to easily add this data through forms, rather than through phpMYadmin.
It seems like I'd be jumping around tables like crazy. is this where the other suggestion of mysql workbench comes in?

Comment: That's pretty much what I'd recommend too. +1 because it's more concise :).

Comment: @JohnMacKenzie learn php and write a simple insert tool ;) Other than that not that I know of.

Comment: This may help for your state table http://www.inkplant.com/code/us-state-mysql-table.php

Comment: I'm sure I can do that :) just figured I'd ask before re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: what does it mean "primary key" would that be my id in my case? is that like an index?

Comment: primary key, googled it , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html :)

Comment: `code`
CREATE TABLE `states` (
id TINYINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`long` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`short` CHAR( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
);

INSERT INTO states VALUES ('Alabama','AL');
`code`
didn't seem to like this...

Comment: long is a reserved word, try longname or something else.

Comment: Also if you aren't going to send an id you need to specify which columns you are inserting into:
`INSERT INTO states (longname,short) VALUES ('Alabama','AL');`

Comment: how do I make state_id point to state.id , or do I just enter the number and a query developed later makes the link?

Comment: You can just enter a number, if you want you can create a foreign key to tie the two together.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html 
It is best to setup the key that will help performance when you do joins.

Comment: so somwething like :
`code`
ALTER TABLE county
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (state_id),
    REFERENCES state(id),
`code`

Comment: also, in club_county , what is the purpose of the ID column... ?

Comment: Not necessary I'm just used to always having an id column because it makes it much easier for some php frameworks.

Comment: `code`
CREATE TABLE club_county (county_id INT NOT NULL,
club_id INT NOT NULL,
INDEX (county_id, club_id),
FOREIGN KEY (county_id)
REFERENCES county(id),
FOREIGN KEY (club_id)
REFERENCES club(id));
`code`

Comment: that seemed to work for that part ... I think, it made a table at least

Comment: I realised I added the foreign key reference to club(id) before club(id) existed... is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, it seems like 1 table will be enough for your needs.  MySQL is so robust that there are many ways to do just about anything.  I recommend downloading and using MySQL Workbench, which makes creating tables, changing tables, and writing queries easier and quicker than embedding them in a webpage.

Download MySQL Workbench -> http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

You will also need to learn a lot about the MySQL queries.  I think you can put all the info that you need in one table, and the trick is which query you use to display the information.

For example, assume you only have 1 table, with all states together.  You can display just the snow mobile clubs from NY state with a query like this:

```
select * from my_table where state = "NY";
```

If you want to display the result alphabetic by Club Name, then you would use something like this:

```
select * from my_table where state = "NY" order by clubname;
```

There is A LOT of documentation online.  So I would suggest doing quite a few hours of research and playing with MySQL Workbench.

The purpose of Stack Overflow is to answer more specific questions that have to do with specific code or queries.  So once you have built a program, and get stumped on something, you can ask the specific question here.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

U can a create a single table with composite key constraint. Like..
I have 3 department in a company and each have multiple num of sub department.so I can create a database like this..
Dept_id || sub_dept_id || Name || Sal || Address || Phone
..where Dept_id and sub_dept_id will jointly represent the primary key and beholds its uniqueness.

> > But remember if ur database is going to be too large,then think before u doing this step,u might need need clustering or index for that  scenario.
> >     While writing SQL query,its good practise to divide a main module in num of sub module. So u can break the Adress.
> >     As per your yes/no.... use integer feild and plan it in a way that if its YES,it'll store 1 else 0(zero)...

Comment: I can say that NY alone has 243 clubs... and some of them are in multiple counties... so that adds another layer , my thought was just to duplicate the info, but I'm sure there's a smarter way....

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make individual tables for the individual counties. What you should do instead is create a table for states, a table for counties, and a table for addresses.

The result could look something like this:

state (id, code, name),
county (id, stateID, name),
club (id, countyID, name, streetAddress, etc...)

The process used to determine what to break up and when is called "database normalisation" - there's actually algorithms that do this for you. The wiki page on that is a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

One long text for the street address is fine, btw, as are varchars for the other fields.

Comment: looks like you and @pitchennate are on the same thread of thought here... , can the club have multiple county id's ? 
https://membership.nyssnowassoc.org/club/show/415

Comment: @JohnMacKenzie Yes I just read him wrong in the original comment. Not my day today :). If your clubs could span multiple counties, the database-ish way would be to modify the `club` table to be like this: `club (id, name, streetAddress, etc...)` and to have another table `clubXcounty` or similar like this: `clubXcounty (clubID, countyID)`. You can then use SQL JOINs in your queries to get all the involved counties. You could also add several countyIDs to the club table instead, but then your SELECTs might end up harder to write and maintain.

Comment: thanks for your help anmd input magnus, I greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: thanks, it's turned into far more of a beast than I'd anticipated, but think it'll be far more useful / functional / resilient  thanks to your input :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Should I really be making multiple tables for each county, such as NY.ALBANY , NY.MADISON

It depends, but in your described case an alternative might be to have one database table with all the snowmobile clubs, and one table for all the states/counties. In the clubs table you could have an id field as foreign key which links the entry to a specific state/county entry.
To get all the info together you'd  just have to do a JOIN-operation on the tables (please refer to mysql documentation).

1. Are the field formats I have chosen the sensible ones?

They would work..

1. Should Address be broken into subcomponents... such as street1, street2, city, state, zip?

Essentially the question here is if you need it broken down into subcomponents, either now or in the future? If it is broken down, you have the data separated which makes further processing (eg generation of serial letters, automated lookups..) potentially simpler, but that depends on your processing; if you don't need it separated why make life more complicated?

so many answers already.. agreed.