# Performing joins

Tags: mysql, join

So this my first run into mysql databases,

I got a lot of help from my first question :
[MYSQL - First Database Structure help Please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774071/mysql-first-database-structure-help-please)

and built my database as pitchinnate recommended

I have :

Table structure for table club

```
Column      Type            Null    Default
id          int(11)         No  
clubname    varchar(100)    No  
address     longtext        No  
phone       varchar(12)     No  
website     varchar(255)    No  
email       varchar(100)    No
```

Table structure for table club_county

```
Column      Type    Null    Default
club_id     int(11) No  
county_id   int(11) No
```

Table structure for table county

```
Column      Type        Null    Default
id          int(11)     No  
state_id    tinyint(4)  No  
name        varchar(50) No
```

Table structure for table states

```
Column      Type        Null    Default
id          tinyint(4)  No  
longstate   varchar(20) No  
shortstate  char(2)     No
```

I set up foreign key relationships for everything above that looks that way.... states.id -> county.state_id for example

What I tried to run :

```
SELECT *
FROM club
JOIN states
JOIN county
  ON county.state_id=states.id
JOIN club_county
  ON club_county.club_id=club.id
club_county.county_id=county.id
```

This didn't work... I'm sure the reason is obvious to those of you who know what SHOULD be done.

What I'm trying to do is

get a listing of all clubs, with their associated state and county(ies)

Comment: @dukeling, thanks for making it more readable, what tags should I be using ?

Comment: For this particular question I wouldn't use tags other than `mysql`, since the question requires pretty standard MySQL knowledge and any other tags are too broad and people who follow these tags don't necessarily know anything about MySQL (though it's a pretty standard SQL `join` query, so that one's not bad). When editing a question, I generally just leave tags that are vaguely related to the question since some people may differ in opinion. I generally just add tags where needed.

Comment: gotcha, how did you edit the readability ?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting help. The buttons at the top of the edit box also usually makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a JOIN condition for each of your joins.  It should look something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM club
JOIN club_county ON club.id = club_county.club_id
JOIN county ON club_county.county_id = county.id
JOIN states ON county.state_id = state.id
```

Your version omitted an ON clause on the line that reads `JOIN states`.

One thing regarding your table names: It's advisable to stick to either singular or plural table names and not to mix them (notice you have `club` (singular) and `states` (plural) tables).  This makes things easier to remember when you're developing and you're less likely to make mistakes.

EDIT:

If you want to limit which columns appear in your result, you just need to modify the SELECT clause. Instead if "SELECT *", you comma separate just the fields you want.

E.g.

```
SELECT club.id, club.name, county.name, states.name
FROM club
JOIN club_county ON club.id = club_county.club_id
JOIN county ON club_county.county_id = county.id
JOIN states ON county.state_id = state.id
```

Comment: gotcha as far as plural/singular.
club_county county id would be from county.id

Comment: You're quite right, there was a typo in my query, I've fixed it for you and tidied it up a little.

Comment: ok, what I'm seeing is a lot closer to what I want....
how do I limit what columns are shown in total from joined tables?

Comment: I've modified my answer to do that for you.

Comment: SELECT club.id, club.clubname, county.name, state.shortstate
FROM club
JOIN club_county ON club.id = club_county.club_id
JOIN county ON club_county.county_id = county.id
JOIN state ON county.state_id = state.id

Comment: worked perfectly, using joins as I wanted to... I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The query you have written will not even execute as it has syntax error.
Please see this link for more details on JOINS:
[13.2.8.2. JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Also, `

```
SELECT * 
FROM club a, county b, states c, club_county d 
WHERE a.id = d.county_id
AND b.id = d.county_id
AND b.state_id = c.id
```

`

I hope this will help... If you still need help, please let us know...

Thanks...
Mr.777

Comment: @JohnMacKenzie :What output you want to see? I just put * instead of the column names, so you can either place any columns you want to see....

Or if there is the problem in results being fetched?


Thanks...
Mr.777

Comment: I see what you're trying to do... I think... :)

each tables own "id" is an autoincrement primary key.
so club.id does not = county.id

Comment: so let's say club # 2 is in state #33 (state.id) and counties (county.id) #1,2,5,8 I'd like to see clubdetails-state-counties

Comment: And if that is the case, I would rather say that the database structure is ambiguous :) Awww, just seen that question has been modified ;)

Answer (score 1):

So after you have modified the question, now the answer would be more like:

```
SELECT club.id,club.clubname,county.name,states.longstate,states.shortstate 
FROM club,club_county,county,states
WHERE club.id=club_county.club_id
AND county.id=club_county.county_id
AND states.id = county.state_id
```

Please let me know if you need more help...

Thanks...
Mr.777

Comment: is this method slower or more system intensive than a "join" ?

Comment: SELECT county.name, states.longstate, club.clubname, club.address, club.phone, club.website, club.email
FROM club, club_county, county, states
WHERE club.id = club_county.club_id
AND county.id = club_county.county_id
AND states.id = county.state_id
ORDERBY club.clubname

Comment: is there any way for it to display the county.name all in one row , say comma seperated ?

Comment: Please find the answer here:
http://hashmysql.org/wiki/Comma_vs_JOIN

Also, use the Explain(query) to check how efficient it is.

Comment: What do you mean by: "display the county.name all in one row"? Can you be more precise? Thanks

Comment: if club "Frontier Sno Riders" is in Counties "Albany" "Madison" "Oneida"  have it display as "Albany,Madison,Oneida" "Frontier Sno Riders"  rather than one line for each county

Comment: Yeah have you ever heard of the term GROUP BY Clause?
This clause will help you in this scenario.

PS: I think the subquery might get you to your result, I am just not pretty much sure of the scenario but surely the requirement you asked for can be fullfilled somehow.

Comment: tried to add a "group by club.clubname" to the end and it got upset at syntax

Comment: Ofcourse it will complain, @JohnMacKenzie you better be try something, put your efforts and if you find nothing, please ask. I am not in the favour of spoon feeding anytime. So, it's for your sake to try, put your efforts and learn....

I have got to go for now.... So, I hope you will try it till tomorrow and if you find nothing, just post your efforts and milestones here and I will have a look and will answer accordingly...
Thanks

Comment: right now it's looking like group_concat is the right track, but is just giving me single lines of everything comma delimited. Will let ya know what comes of it.